# How can I compare two dates in vbscript/ASP?

Tags: date, asp-classic, vbscript

Using ASP classic, I need to somehow compare two dates with each other. How can I do this?

Answer (score 25):

```
Date1 = #rs["date"]#
Date2 = #12/1/2009#


If DateDiff("d", Date1, Date2) > 1 Then
    response.write "This date is before 12/1/2009"
Else
    response.write "This date is after 12/1/2009"
End If
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using `DateDiff` instead of comparing the Dates directly?

Comment: You can choose the amount of difference that's significant (days, months, weeks).

Comment: +1 to Broam's response, plus IMHO it is better programming practice to compare on the parameter you can compare on vs. a "blind" compare.

Answer (score 18):

```
If Date1 > Date2 Then
  ' Date1 occurred after Date 2
End If
```

Use `>`, `<` and `=` like comparing numbers (and `>=`, `<=` and `<>` too). Smaller dates are more historic.

This of course assumes that `Date1` and `Date2` are actually Date or DateTime objects. If they aren't, you'll need to convert them to Date objects first using `CDate()`.

Comment: In vbscript, they are always variants, however IsDate() can be used to check  that the values can be implicitly cast as dates - often worthwhile IMHO.