# Check if a date is greater than a specified date

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I want to check if a date is greater than a specified date using VBScript in Classic ASP.

The same thing i got working in the following :

[Check if a date is greater than specified date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344471/check-if-a-date-is-greater-than-specified-date/38344660?noredirect=1#comment64104240_38344660)

but the above is using javascript.

I did it using JavaScript as :

```js
var Jun16 = new Date('JUN-2016')
var SelectedDate=new Date("<% =session("month")%>" + "-" + "<% =session("yrs")%>")

if(SelectedDate.getTime() > Jun16.getTime())
{
grossinc=parseInt("<% =rset1("othermontize_benefit") %>") + parseInt("<% =rset1("basic") %>") + parseInt("<% =rset1("house") %>") + parseInt("<% =rset1("utility") %>")
}
else
{
grossinc=parseInt("<% =rset1("gross") %>") + parseInt("<% =rset1("bonus") %>") + parseInt("<% =rset1("arrears") %>") + parseInt("<% =rset1("ot") %>")

}
```

How can I get the same in vb in classic asp.

**EDIT :**

the data which is to be compared is in MON AND YYYY format , there is no such any date , month is selected from months dropdown in MON Format and year is selected from years dropdown in yyyy format , now i want to check if the selected criteria is greater than JUN-2016 ?

Thanks.

Comment: I want to check that if selected criteria is greater than JUN-2016 or not

Comment: But which date in June?????????

Comment: No any date is specified , if the employee want to generate the pay slip of Month June , he will select June and 2016 from the dropdowns not the Date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compare two dates in vbscript/ASP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327169/how-can-i-compare-two-dates-in-vbscript-asp)

Comment: @MattWilko no any answer helped me here , i solved my problem using query logics , i'll add the solution later

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work for you:

```
jun16 = CDate("Jun-2016") ' jun16 = 01/06/2016 00:00:00
selectedDate = CDate(Session("month") & "-" & Session("year"))

If selectedDate > jun16 Then
    Response.Write("Geater")
Else
    Response.Write("Less than or equal to")
End If
```

Comment: sorry , actually i dont know any thing about vb , i am working on a project of classic asp where vb is used ,how can i do it in classic asp using vb :(

Comment: SORRY :( I modified it

Comment: the data which is to be compared is in MON AND YYYY format , there is no such any date , month is selected from months dropdown in MON Format and year is selected from years dropdown in yyyy format , now i want to check if the selected criteria is greater than JUN-2016 ?

Comment: it could be any day , the condition is depends upon the month and year , if the employee is generating the payslip of june 2016 the criteria will be different and after June 2016 criteria will be changed

Comment: In your suggested solution , How can I pass session("month") and session("yrs") at the place of selectedDate = Now

Comment: Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'

Expected end of statement

/payslip.asp, line 282

Dim jun16 as Date
----------^

Comment: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: 'CDate'

/payslip.asp, line 283

Comment: `MsgBox()` is client-side VBScript won't work in server-side VBScript in Classic ASP use `Response.Write()`.

Comment: I want to upvote the second example, but downvote the first since it doesn't match the question in any way, shape, or form. Hence, no vote from me. :/

Comment: @Martha - it did when the question was originally posted and tagged as VB.NET. I will remove that part now...

Comment: @MattWilko: ah, that explains it.